# Tango Unity Examples crashing on Unity 5.3.6f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm trying to run the *Augmented reality* example from the samples repository:
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity

It starts fine, everything works, I can drop pins and they are being tracked perfectly, but depending on light conditions the app crashes.
I can't point it to windows, and the same happens if I cover the camera with my hands.

Here is the stack trace:

```
I/DEBUG   (  164): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  164): Build fingerprint: 'google/tango/yellowstone:4.4.2/KOT49H.160624/160624002:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  164): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  164): pid: 3665, tid: 3665, name: o.unityexamples  >>> com.projecttango.unityexamples <<<
I/DEBUG   (  164): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
W/st-log  ( 1714): Final features: 572
W/st-log  ( 1714): Initial features: Max - 8682, Min - 8851
I/DEBUG   (  164):     r0 52372a58  r1 bece1160  r2 00000025  r3 5015d520
I/DEBUG   (  164):     r4 00000025  r5 00000025  r6 52372a58  r7 5015d520
I/DEBUG   (  164):     r8 00000028  r9 000000fe  sl 4049ea99  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     ip 00020002  sp bece1150  lr 4049b0e1  pc 00000000  cpsr 60030010
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d0  410000003f000000  d1  410800003f000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d2  42400000429b0000  d3  0000003042420000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d4  42b8000000000000  d5  4220000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d6  4220000000000028  d7  c220000042220000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d8  0000004d3f000000  d9  00000028fffffff8
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d10 3f80000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d14 44e6000000000000  d15 4314000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d16 3ff0000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d18 3ff0000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d22 4057000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 4057000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     d30 3fc26b82802435f9  d31 3f876de24755e5ac
I/DEBUG   (  164):     scr 20000012
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #01  pc 000920df  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapProcShader::shadeSpan(int, int, unsigned int*, int)+84)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #02  pc 000998a1  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkARGB32_Shader_Blitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int)+340)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #03  pc 000c280d  /system/lib/libskia.so
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #04  pc 000c28ef  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillIRect(SkIRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+222)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #05  pc 000c29b5  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+136)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #06  pc 000c2aa1  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRasterClip const&, SkBlitter*)+52)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #07  pc 000a571b  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawRect(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&) const+256)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #08  pc 000a26bf  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDevice::drawBitmapRect(SkDraw const&, SkBitmap const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const&)+590)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #09  pc 0009e245  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkCanvas::internalDrawBitmapRect(SkBitmap const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const*)+176)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #10  pc 00079a31  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (NinePatch_Draw(SkCanvas*, SkRect const&, SkBitmap const&, android::Res_png_9patch const&, SkPaint const*, SkRegion**)+1252)
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #11  pc 000794c5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #12  pc 00d065a4  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.oat
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1110  3f000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1114  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1118  bece1164  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece111c  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1120  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1124  4049eb05  /system/lib/libskia.so
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1128  52372a58  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece112c  bece1164  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1130  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1134  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1138  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece113c  52372a58  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1140  5015d520  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1144  00000028
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1148  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece114c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #00  bece1150  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #01  bece1150  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1154  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1158  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece115c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1160  00000008
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1164  00010000
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1168  00030002
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece116c  00050004
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1170  00070006
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1174  00090008
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1178  000b000a
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece117c  000d000c
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1180  000f000e
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1184  00110010
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1188  00130012
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece118c  00150014
I/DEBUG   (  164):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #02  bece1388  00000025
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece138c  404cd203  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::AntiFillRect(SkRect const&, SkRasterClip const&, SkBlitter*)+18)
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1390  400f1000  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1394  4f961a1c  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece1398  00000028
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece139c  40559715  /system/lib/libskia.so (S32A_Opaque_BlitRow32_neon_src_alpha(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*, int, unsigned int))
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13a0  00000001
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13a4  52964aec  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13a8  534e8bf8  /dev/nvmap
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13ac  404a274d  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkARGB32_Shader_Blitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int))
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13b0  00000028
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13b4  bece13e8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13b8  bece19c8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13bc  00000758
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13c0  00000028
I/DEBUG   (  164):          bece13c4  bece1e20  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a38 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000007e
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a48 00000025 00000038 00010003 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a58 52372ae0 3f800000 00000000 c2200000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a68 00000000 3f800000 41000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a78 00000000 3f800000 00000011 404b719f
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a88 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a98 501564a8 523721c8 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372aa8 4049e559 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ab8 00000000 00010000 00000000 00010100
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ac8 00000000 00000000 00000000 4049ea99
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ad8 00000000 40557769 00000000 4df04c80
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ae8 00002274 00000001 4ab2a280 5014b838
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372af8 0000007e 00000025 00000038 00010003
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372b08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372b18 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372b28 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1140 5015d520 00000028 df0027ad 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1150 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1160 00000008 00010000 00030002 00050004
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1170 00070006 00090008 000b000a 000d000c
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1180 000f000e 00110010 00130012 00150014
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1190 00170016 00190018 001b001a 001d001c
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11a0 001f001e 00210020 00230022 00000024
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1210 00000000 00000000 0000011a 00000091
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1220 0000006e 40a00000 00000000 41f13333
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1230 00000000 40000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near r3:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d500 00001800 01001800 0e000400 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d510 00000000 17000000 400b5fee 00001e0b
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d520 00000130 66727553 56656361 3a776569
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d530 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d540 00000000 00000000 00000058 675f3536
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d550 6130326b 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d560 00000000 00000000 00000000 6f68766e
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d570 735f7473 00636e79 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d580 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d590 15327225 00000062 00000041 0000159b
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5a0 00000058 675f3637 6130326b 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5c0 00000000 6f68766e 735f7473 00636e79
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5e0 00000000 00000001 15327b95 00000062
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5f0 0000004c 000012d9 00000058 645f3032
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a38 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000007e
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a48 00000025 00000038 00010003 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a58 52372ae0 3f800000 00000000 c2200000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a68 00000000 3f800000 41000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a78 00000000 3f800000 00000011 404b719f
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a88 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372a98 501564a8 523721c8 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372aa8 4049e559 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ab8 00000000 00010000 00000000 00010100
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ac8 00000000 00000000 00000000 4049ea99
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ad8 00000000 40557769 00000000 4df04c80
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372ae8 00002274 00000001 4ab2a280 5014b838
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372af8 0000007e 00000025 00000038 00010003
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372b08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372b18 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     52372b28 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d500 00001800 01001800 0e000400 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d510 00000000 17000000 400b5fee 00001e0b
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d520 00000130 66727553 56656361 3a776569
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d530 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d540 00000000 00000000 00000058 675f3536
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d550 6130326b 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d560 00000000 00000000 00000000 6f68766e
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d570 735f7473 00636e79 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d580 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d590 15327225 00000062 00000041 0000159b
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5a0 00000058 675f3637 6130326b 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5c0 00000000 6f68766e 735f7473 00636e79
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5e0 00000000 00000001 15327b95 00000062
I/DEBUG   (  164):     5015d5f0 0000004c 000012d9 00000058 645f3032
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049ea78 19f64622 f7ff1b2d 42a5fd71 2d00daf6
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049ea88 4630dd04 462a2100 fd68f7ff 0000bdfe
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049ea98 43f7e92d 4606ad02 f8df4614 f8458080
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eaa8 461a1d04 9b0a4629 ff1cf7ff 44f86833
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eab8 98014601 2e0169de 2100d104 f7f50062
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eac8 e028ed2e 46052900 4249da0e bfb442a1
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049ead8 4627460f ea4f2100 464a0947 ed1ef7f5
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eae8 d0181be4 2100444d da0b42b1 46281a77
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eaf8 bfa842a7 463a4627 fd30f7ff d00a1be4
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb08 0547eb05 1e714806 f858b289 46282000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb18 46226813 e8bd4798 bf0083fe 0012012e
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb28 fffff2ec 4ff0e92d ee06b08b eef63a10
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb38 46047a00 ed9d468b 6ca10a14 6c024615
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb48 f10bab08 eef80b08 6c406ac6 eeb86ce6
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb58 6ae77ac0 92039105 1d209004 ee769606
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049eb68 ee370aa7 ee101a27 ee111a90 47b82a10
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     0001ffe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     0001fff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00020090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000200a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000200b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000200c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000200d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1130 00000025 00000025 00000025 52372a58
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1140 5015d520 00000028 df0027ad 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1150 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1160 00000008 00010000 00030002 00050004
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1170 00070006 00090008 000b000a 000d000c
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1180 000f000e 00110010 00130012 00150014
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1190 00170016 00190018 001b001a 001d001c
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11a0 001f001e 00210020 00230022 00000024
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece11f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1210 00000000 00000000 0000011a 00000091
I/DEBUG   (  164):     bece1220 0000006e 40a00000 00000000 41f13333
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):     000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  164):
I/DEBUG   (  164): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b0c0 454d9b03 462cbfb4 4630464c 4622a904
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b0d0 46439300 463047d0 4622a904 47d8463b
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b0e0 d0031b2d eb0744a0 e7e90784 7d05f50d
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b0f0 8ff0e8bd 4ff0e92d 7d05f5ad 4100f8d0
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b100 461f4688 9d8e9203 0688f100 9500b11c
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b110 47a04630 f8d0e01f f44fa104 f8d07100
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b120 4630b10c f96af003 9b034681 bfb4454d
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b130 464c462c a9044630 93004622 47d04643
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b140 a9044630 463b4622 1b2d47d8 44a0d003
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b150 0744eb07 f50de7e9 e8bd7d05 b5108ff0
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b160 f5004604 f7fd7088 f104fd2d f0020088
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b170 4620fe9e 4010e8bd ba32f005 4604b570
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b180 461d4616 4608b121 015cf104 fe24f7fd
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b190 4630b116 f9d4f01c f894b12d 602b30f7
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b1a0 00f8f894 20016068 305cbd70 befcf7fd
I/DEBUG   (  164):     4049b1b0 460cb538 f0334605 6823fbb1 f1054620
W/st-log  ( 1714): Final features: 0
W/st-log  ( 1714): Initial features: Max - 9169, Min - 9271
W/st-log  ( 1714): Final features: 0
I/BootReceiver(  914): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   Force finishing activity com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity
W/InputDispatcher(  914): channel '6525a508 com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  914): channel '6525a508 com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/tango   ( 1714): TangoService.cc:138 ThreadLoop attempting disconnect number 0.
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:576 TangoContext::StopRuntime()
I/tango   ( 1714): path-utility.cc:315 Recursive reset of all ownership on: /data/data/com.google.tango/files/datasets/ to match: /data/data/com.google.tango/files/datasets/
D/phs:ipc-loc(  184): Socket 12: hangup from client "com.projecttango.unityexamples"
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:1721 TangoContext: Stopping Tango Service Application.
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:1578 Logging 1 events.
W/MediaFocusControl(  914):   AudioFocus   audio focus client died
I/MediaFocusControl(  914): AudioFocus  removeFocusStackEntry(): removing entry for android.os.BinderProxy@651f2f00
W/InputDispatcher(  914): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '6525a508 com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)'
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 8000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 40 1F 00 00 74
I/WindowState(  914): WIN DEATH: Window{6525a508 u0 com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}
W/tango   ( 1714): tango-xyzij-callback.cc:125 No points in point cloud.
W/tango   ( 1714): tango-xyzij-callback.cc:125 No points in point cloud.
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-service-application.cc:310 TangoServiceApplication: Stopping service application...
I/tango   ( 1714): data-manager.cc:1222 Behind by: 0.235318 seconds, skip current frame.
I/WindowState(  914): WIN DEATH: Window{652a1570 u0 SurfaceView}
W/st-log  ( 1714): Initial features: Max - 9625, Min - 9756
I/tango   ( 1714): data-manager.cc:1222 Behind by: 0.134141 seconds, skip current frame.
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 36 0C 00 74
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 31 0C 00 74
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 10000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0B 04 10 27 00 00 74
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 8000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 40 1F 00 00 74
W/ActivityManager(  914): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager(  914): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:768)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2473)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2347)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2045)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9569)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9462)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10107)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9658)
W/ActivityManager(  914):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
I/art     (  914): GcCauseBackground sticky partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4038(285KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(848KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 15MB/17MB, paused 9.680ms total 28.066ms
W/JavaBinder(  914): Binder has been finalized when calling linkToDeath() with recip=0x47695aa8)
I/ActivityManager(  914): Process com.projecttango.unityexamples (pid 3665) has died.
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 10000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0B 04 10 27 00 00 74
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 8000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 40 1F 00 00 74
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 20000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0B 04 20 4E 00 00 74
I/art     (  166): Process 3665 terminated by signal (11)
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 10000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 10 27 00 00 74
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 36 10 00 74
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 31 10 00 74
W/InputMethodManagerService(  914): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 3665 uid 10119
W/Binder  ( 1178): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
W/Binder  ( 1178): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSession android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodSessionWrapper.getInternalInputMethodSession()' on a null object reference
W/Binder  ( 1178):  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
W/Binder  ( 1178):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
W/Binder  ( 1178):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
W/st-log  ( 1714): Final features: 0
W/tango   ( 1714): tango-xyzij-callback.cc:125 No points in point cloud.
E/libgps  (  914): HandleGpsExtensionMessage: The handler for GPSE_MSG is not assigned
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  170): routeResultFromCAM: WARNING: only 0 requests in flight on sensor 0, frame drops likely
W/SQLiteConnectionPool( 1373): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
W/SQLiteConnectionPool( 1373): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
W/SQLiteConnectionPool( 1373): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  170): routeResultFromCAM: WARNING: only 0 requests in flight on sensor 1, frame drops likely
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  170): NvCamScaler_OutputThread-- (error 0x0)
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  170): SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 1
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 10000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 10 27 00 00 74
I/Camera2ClientBase(  170): Closed Camera 1
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-service-application.cc:336 TangoServiceApplication: Joined successfully.
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:1729 Trying to reset application_.
I/tango   ( 1714): manager.cc:133 IMU average latency 0.716335ms variance 1.09216 max 15.9455ms hz 100.12
I/tango   ( 1714): manager.cc:139 VIO average latency 23.7695ms variance 67.4392 max 51.9662ms hz 9.95672
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-hal-interface.cc:98 Average feature detection frequency: 10.0681
I/tango   ( 1714): feature_tracker.cc:65 Total num. of frame-frame matches before RANSAC: 110348
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  170): NvCamScaler_OutputThread-- (error 0x0)
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  170): SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 1
E/Sensors (  914): [nosae] setDelay: 20000000 sec
D/Sensors (  914): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 20 4E 00 00 74
E/st-log  ( 1714):
E/st-log  ( 1714):
E/st-log  ( 1714):
E/st-log  ( 1714):
I/tango   ( 1714): tango_hal_wrapper.cc:90 Closing Tango HAL.
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:1731 Done resetting application_.
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:1578 Logging 3 events.
I/Camera2ClientBase(  170): Closed Camera 0
I/tango   ( 1714): tango-context.cc:1735 TangoContext: Runtime has shut down!
I/tango   ( 1714): path-utility.cc:315 Recursive reset of all ownership on: /data/data/com.google.tango/files/ to match: /data/data/com.google.tango/files/
I/tango   ( 1714): TangoService.cc:142 ThreadLoop stopped Tango Runtime.
```

As far as I can understand, it's crashing on a system library `/system/lib/libskia.so`.

Has anyone seen it? Is there a way to avoid it by downgrading a library? How?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues seem releated with UX Library, Could you disable and try again.
or Could you try to build on older Unity SDK
like 5.3.3f1 or older.